# Converting a DWORD value into a QString

Tags: qt, qstring, dword

I have the following method in QT:

```
QString getHDDSerial() {
  DWORD dwVolSerial;
  BOOL bIsRetrieved;
  bIsRetrieved = GetVolumeInformation(L"C:\\", NULL, NULL, &dwVolSerial, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  qDebug() << dwVolSerial;
  if (bIsRetrieved) {
      return dwVolSerial;
  } else {
      return "error";
  }
}
```

How can I return the dwVolSerial as a QString?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22105

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt: Which is better for transforming a number to QString, QVariant or QString::number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287602/qt-which-is-better-for-transforming-a-number-to-qstring-qvariant-or-qstringn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it done with this:

```
return QString::number(dwVolSerial);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format serial number as the `dir` console command does (i.e. like `2210-0DD0`), you can use the following code:

```
qDebug() << QString().sprintf("%04X-%04X", 
                              HIWORD(dwVolSerial), LOWORD(dwVolSerial));
```

It's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777403/344347) adapted for Qt.